Windows 11 Desktop background suddenly disappeared
Just a couple of minutes ago I was casually watching YouTube until I saw my background picture vanish on my second screen I closed my browser and saw, that my main screen picture was also gone.
I immediately did four things:

Check the customization settings, to see whether it changed somehow... The background was now set to solid color (black) for some reason
Check the event log for any unusual activity... Nothing eye catching there
Checked Defender and ran a quick scan (just to be sure)
Run Wireshark and look for weird aka. unexpected traffic, which might indicate remote access of some kind or screen capturing (since some screen capture software turns the screen to black, I thought this might be a good idea). I have pretty good control over my network and everything looked pretty ordinary there.

I also read that Windows Update can apparently cause this kind of behavior, but this usually manifests after a reboot and not while operating normally.
So I came here and was wondering if any of you might know why this might have happened, or have observed this behavior yourselves. Does this have something to do with / can this be explained with "expectable Windows shenanigans"?!
I am running:
Edition:    Windows 11 Pro
Version:    23H2
Installed:  ‎11.‎11.‎2023
OS build:   22631.3737
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1009.0
Latest update happened yesterday (28/06/2024).
Edit: It came back 20min later... and then disappeared again, as soon as I was checking the "Personalize section", even though it was still set to picture...
I get a feeling, this might be a Windows bug.

It does happen to others: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-background-disappeared/3a54b035-465a-4d13-b779-5ff703f03176 Microsoft suggests using SFC and DISM to scan Windows for issues.. Also, be sure you don't have the background image set to switch automatically.

@DrMoishePippik That is a different problem. It describes the background picture being gone after an update and restart and the settings app being broken.
There was neither an update nor did my computer restart. It just disappeared and the settings app was working perfectly fine. Just the setting changed (multiple times) on its own.
And no, my settings are not set to switch automatically. I didn't change it in months.
